# XML/Django not displaying the XML properly?

Tags: xml, django, django-templates

I am trying to pass data from a model into a XML file. I do this like I would with a normal .html template:

```
def getGroups(request):
    groups = SpeciesGroup.objects.all().order_by('id')
    return render_to_response(
        'groups.xml',
        {'groups':groups},
        context_instance = RequestContext(request)
    )
```

in my groups.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Groups>
    {% for g in groups %}
    <group_id>{{g.id}}</group_id>
    <name>{{g.name}}</name> 
    <description>{{g.description}}</description>
    {% endfor %}
</Groups>
```

When loading the URL in the browser, I get a blank screen.  But when I view source I get the correct data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Groups>
    <group_id>1</group_id>
    <name>Small</name> 
    <description>Small</description>

    <group_id>2</group_id>
    <name>Medium</name> 
    <description>Medium</description>

    <group_id>3</group_id>
    <name>Large</name> 
    <description>Large</description>
</Groups>
```

I have validated the source XML and it's fine. I'm assuming I have missed something or left something out in my view. I bet it's something simple that I can't find on a Monday morning!

Comment: I figured it out myself! all I needed was to add the mimetype in my return:

    return render_to_response('groups.xml', {'groups':groups}, context_instance = RequestContext(request), mimetype='application/xml')

Comment: please add this as an answer and accept it (to help other so users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself! All I needed was to add the **mimetype** in my return:

```
return render_to_response(
    'groups.xml',
    {'groups':groups},
    context_instance = RequestContext(request),
    mimetype='application/xml'
)
```